# My delete button does not delete the right post

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have this delete button with a dialog on it but the button does not get the id of the post right and I think it always starts to delete from the first post so I end up deleting them all also every user can see the delete button on other users post too I want them to only see the delete button on their own posts with every account that they log in
I will appreciate your help

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import post
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

  



def detail(request, id):
     poost = get_object_or_404(post, pk=id)
     return render(request, "posts/detail.html", {"post": poost})

@login_required()
def delete(request, id):
     poost = get_object_or_404(post, pk=id)
     poost.delete()
     messages.error(request, f'Post deleted!')
     return redirect("/")

@login_required()
def new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         form = PostForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
              form.instance.author = request.user
              form.save()
              messages.success(request, f'Post created!')
              return redirect("/")   
           
    else:
         form = PostForm()
    return render(request, "posts/new.html", {"form": form })
```

my post.html (where delete button is)

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" id="deleteButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"/>
            <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"/>
          </svg></a>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Delete Confirmation Modal</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <div class="icon-box">
          </div>                
          <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>    
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p  class="text-muted">Do you really want to delete {{ post.title }}? This process cannot be undone.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>     
  </body>
  </html>
</div>
```

detail.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}

<html>
  <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
  <body class="text-center" style="line-height: 2;">
    <article>
      <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
      <p style="margin-top: 15px;">{{post.body}}</p>
    </article>
  </body>
  <div style="margin-top: 24px"></div>
  <a style="color: darkgray; font-size: 22px;"> <img  src="{% static 'website/icons8-sparkles-25.png'%}"> Written by {{post.author}} <img  src="{% static 'website/icons8-sparkles-25.png'%}"> </a>
</html>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: in HTML  you should use `{% if %}` to check `user == post.author` and add or skip button `Delete`. But also in `python` code you should check if `user == post.author` before you delete post because someone can send fake request to delete post.

Comment: You shouldn't use an `<html>` in another `<html>`. Keep only the `<div id="myModal">`.

Comment: I updated the question I think it is that `{{post.body}}` part please check it out thanks